# angular select bind dictionary

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I try to bind the options of an  to an dictionary:

```
<select ng-model="vm.incident.State" ng-options="key for (key,value) in vm.stateOptionSet" style="width: 250px;">
```

as far everything works fine, but when I use this:

```
<select ng-model="vm.incident.State" ng-options="key as value for (key,value) in vm.stateOptionSet" style="width: 250px;">
```

The Selectbox didn't select the entry which fits to the ng-model.

Can someone tell me whats wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Both of your examples are working. 
Take a look to my example:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="" ng-controller="customersController">
  <select ng-model="selection" ng-options="key for (key,value) in optionSet" style="width: 250px;"></select>
  <select ng-model="selection" ng-options="key as value for (key,value) in optionSet" style="width: 250px;"></select>
  <br />Selection: {{selection}}
</div>
<script>
  function customersController($scope) {
    $scope.selection = {};
    $scope.optionSet = {
      key1: "value1",
      key2: "value2"
    };
  }
</script>
```

Maybe you have forgotten that you have to close your select tag.

Comment: Maybe I should add, that the model is only a number, which is the key of the dictionary pairs

Comment: Your stateOptionSet is an array? I don't understand your problem.

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions):

> Using `select as` will bind the result of the select expression to the *model*, but the value of the `<select>` and `<option>` html elements will be either the **index** (for array data sources) **or property name** (for object data sources) of the value within the collection. If a `track by` expression is used, the result of that expression will be set as the **value of the option** and select elements.